# Android LibVlc integration and streaming issues (slow stream, stuttering, only audio play etc)

Tags: android, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, libvlc, audiovideoplayback

I want to integrate libvlc in my Android app to play live video stream that is in m3u8 format. To achieve that I have downloaded a sample source code from [here](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample/src) that is a demo to play videos. It is mentioned that we have to first compile vlc for android to run this sample code. For that we must follow this process [androidcompile](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile) and must be on linux. So instead of following that process i have found an sdk [vlc-android-sdk](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk) in which vlc code is already compiled for armeabi-v7a and it contains already generated .so files.

Now i have successfully imported that sdk code into sample source code and it works but with following issues:

1) Very slow streaming. After some seconds 6-7 sec it get stuck and then play after very long time again.
2) Sometimes it play video stream for 5-6 seconds and then gets stuck and never play again.
3) Video stream does not play for very long interval of time like 20-30 minutes.
4) Video starts very late.
5) In some devices on start it show video for 2-3 seconds but then video stops and only audio keeps playing.
6) Some streams does not even play at some devices.

So is the above mentioned way (using  vlc-android-sdk) to achieve vlc integration the right way? or we must compile the libvlc first on linux (doing that whole lengthy process). If yes then what could be the possible reasons of above mentioned issues. Any suggestions or solution?

Comment: Did you get any solution on this ? I am also trying to achieve the same

Comment: no i haven't got any solution i have removed libvlc from the project

Comment: I am also facing same issue. I use exoplayer that works fine but that doen't support rtsp :(

Comment: same here. libVLC supports RTMP. Exoplayer has extension but not working.